# ¿Por qué Django entra en recursión al guardar datos de un formulario?

Tags: python, django

Soy nueva en django, estoy haciendo un curso. Voy por la parte de modelos
relacionados e introduzco registros de prueba mediante el administrador de
django. Cuando abrí mi modelo persona (El cual es el del problema ahora) e
introduje los datos del formulario, al hacer click para enviar el formulario
salta el error que dejaré aquí abajo.  No sé porque hay recursión si no he
creado funciones que tengan recursividad. Alguien me puede explicar porque pasa
y como arreglarlo porfa?  Les dejo el codigo de los dos modelos que relacioné y
el error que obtuve.

Modelo departamento:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class departamento(models.Model):

    AREA_CHOICES=[
    #first item, name used by database. second item, text displayed on screen
        ('RRHH','rrhh'),
        ('IT','it'),
        ('fz','finanzas')
    ]
    name= models.CharField('nombre',max_length=50) #null=True, blank=true
    short_name= models.CharField('short name',max_length=20, unique=True)
    annulate= models.BooleanField('Anulado', default=False)
    area= models.CharField(max_length=4,choices=AREA_CHOICES,default='rrhh')


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)+' : '+self.name+'-'+self.short_name
```

Modelo persona:

```
from django.db import models
from applications.departamento.models import departamento

# Create your models here.

JOBS=(
    ('0','programador'),
    ('1','contador'),
    ('2','economista'),
)
class persona(models.Model):
    firstname= models.CharField('firstname',max_length=60)
    lastname= models.CharField('lastname',max_length=60)
    job= models.CharField('Job',max_length=1,choices=JOBS, default='programador')
    departamento= models.ForeignKey(departamento,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE) #relacion uno a muchos
    #imagen= models.ImageField() Sqlite3 no sopoorta bien las imagenes
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self).id+'. '+self.firstname+' '+self.lastname+self.job
```

El error:

```
RecursionError at /admin/persona/persona/add/

maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Request Method: POST
Request URL: https://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/persona/add/
Django Version: 2.2.15
Exception Type: RecursionError
Exception Value: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
Exception Location: /home/yohanna/python projects/practica2/project02/applications/persona/models.py in __str__, line 18
Python Executable: /home/yohanna/python projects/practica2/pythonAppVenv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path: ['/home/yohanna/python projects/practica2/project02',
              '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
              '/usr/lib/python3.5',
              '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
              '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
              '/home/yohanna/python '
              'projects/practica2/pythonAppVenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
Server time: Sáb, 22 Ago 2020 16:23:49 +0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en esta parte:

```
class persona(models.Model):
    # ...

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self).id+'. '+self.firstname+' '+self.lastname+self.job
    #          ^^^^^^^^^
```

Le estas pasando `self` (una referencia al propio objeto) como argumento a
`str`.  Si un objeto define un método `__str__`, `str` lo usa para convertir el
objeto en una cadena.  Así que entra en recursión porque dentro de ese método
también llamas a `str` y ese a su vez vuelve a llamar a `__str__`.

Probablemente querías pasar la id a una cadena y no el propio objeto así que la
solución sería cambiarlo por esto:

```
class persona(models.Model):
    # ...

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)+'. '+self.firstname+' '+self.lastname+self.job
    #          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```